# How to get PHP-FPM status via CLI or pure FastCGI

Tags: php, bash, monitoring, fastcgi, fpm

I want to get PHP-FPM `/status?full` page via CLI. In one command, or with a bash script, I need to display the most verbose output that the PHP process manager can return but without using nginx or apache. I'm using a unix socket located in `/var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In debian, you can use these commands:

```
sudo apt install -y libfcgi0ldbl
sudo -u www-data SCRIPT_NAME=/status \
                 SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status \
                 QUERY_STRING=full \
                 REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
                 cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php5.6-fpm.sock
```

Here is the output

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      ondemand
start time:           21/Jul/2017:11:44:35 +0200
start since:          48122714
accepted conn:        23412055
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       1
active processes:     1
total processes:      2
max active processes: 5
max children reached: 622
slow requests:        0

************************
pid:                  21554
state:                Idle
start time:           29/Jan/2019:09:55:19 +0100
start since:          870
requests:             171
request duration:     109
request method:       GET
request URI:          -?full
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               -
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  2097152

************************
pid:                  20633
state:                Running
start time:           29/Jan/2019:09:24:04 +0100
start since:          2745
requests:             563
request duration:     122
request method:       GET
request URI:          /status?full
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               -
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0
```

Comment: how did you get this output? I see only http headers and response body

Comment: add this in your fpm *.conf file
`pm.status_path=/status`